# Save images of cloudKit to icloud with folder structure

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit, icloud-drive

In my application I can upload image and store it in cloudkit also fetch that images and show in my app as well.
My requirement is save cloudkit image in iCloud with proper folder structure.

cloudkit is enable using developer account but images I want to store in iCloud is different account.

Is there any way to get cloudkit ckasset images in icloud/icloud drive storage.